# Python Tkinter select whole text with left click

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like for the user to be able to copy to his clipboard the text from a text widget in tkinter just by using his left mouse button. As in: the user clicks on the text with the mouse left button, the whole text in the text widget is selected (with the blue lines in windows) and it is copied automatically to the clipboard.

i've tried both frame.bind method and clipboard_append but was unsuccesfull

I've tried 2 options:

Option 1 with clipboard, this one works but in the background (the text is copied when a button is clicked and not when a user clicks on the text, also the text is not selected with blue lines like in windows so the user does not know the text was copied, it just copies the text in the background without the user knowledge):

```
field_value = self.txt.get("1.0", 'end-1c')  # get field value from event, but remove line return at end
txt_frm.clipboard_clear()  # clear clipboard contents
txt_frm.clipboard_append(field_value)  # append new value to clipbaord
```

Option 2 with binding method to button, this one doesn't work at all:

```
def copy_text_to_clipboard(event):
    field_value = event.widget.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
    window.clipboard_clear()  # clear clipboard contents
    window.clipboard_append(field_value)  # append new value to clipbaord


    text_field.bind("<Button-1>", copy_text_to_clipboard)
```

Comment: There is already a well-written answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801557/select-all-text-in-a-text-widget-using-python-3-with-tkinter).

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does the program crash? Does it put the wrong thing on the clipboard? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

try this method :

```
def select_all(event=None):
    text_field.select_range(0, END)
    return "break"

text_field.bind('<Button-1>', select_all)
```